# Fatal error when I try to open MapActivity from ItemOptions

Tags: android, google-maps

I try to create app where I have Main activity, and MapActivity after clicked Options Item - Map. I can't fix this.

```
02-25 22:39:48.956: E/AndroidRuntime(22525): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-25 22:39:48.956: E/AndroidRuntime(22525): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class **{pl.pawelfrydrych.flyingball/pl.pawelfrydrych.flyingball.Map}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?**
02-25 22:39:48.956: E/AndroidRuntime(22525):    at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1645)
02-25 22:39:48.956: E/AndroidRuntime(22525):    at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1441)
02-25 22:39:48.956: E/AndroidRuntime(22525):    at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3464)
02-25 22:39:48.956: E/AndroidRuntime(22525):    at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3425)
02-25 22:39:48.956: E/AndroidRuntime(22525):    at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3661)
02-25 22:39:48.956: E/AndroidRuntime(22525):    at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3629)
02-25 22:39:48.956: E/AndroidRuntime(22525):    at pl.pawelfrydrych.flyingball.MainActivity.onOptionsItemSelected(MainActivity.java:166)
02-25 22:39:48.956: E/AndroidRuntime(22525):    at android.app.Activity.onMenuItemSelected(Activity.java:2640)
02-25 22:39:48.956: E/AndroidRuntime(22525):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.onMenuItemSelected(PhoneWindow.java:1171)
02-25 22:39:48.956: E/AndroidRuntime(22525):    at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.dispatchMenuItemSelected(MenuBuilder.java:735)
02-25 22:39:48.956: E/AndroidRuntime(22525):    at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:152)
02-25 22:39:48.956: E/AndroidRuntime(22525):    at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:874)
02-25 22:39:48.956: E/AndroidRuntime(22525):    at com.android.internal.view.menu.ListMenuPresenter.onItemClick(ListMenuPresenter.java:178)
02-25 22:39:48.956: E/AndroidRuntime(22525):    at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:301)
02-25 22:39:48.956: E/AndroidRuntime(22525):    at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1510)
02-25 22:39:48.956: E/AndroidRuntime(22525):    at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:3333)
02-25 22:39:48.956: E/AndroidRuntime(22525):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
02-25 22:39:48.956: E/AndroidRuntime(22525):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
02-25 22:39:48.956: E/AndroidRuntime(22525):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-25 22:39:48.956: E/AndroidRuntime(22525):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5419)
02-25 22:39:48.956: E/AndroidRuntime(22525):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-25 22:39:48.956: E/AndroidRuntime(22525):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
02-25 22:39:48.956: E/AndroidRuntime(22525):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1187)
```

I see this error with have you declared this activity in AndroidManifest, but I can't manage to do.

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch(item.getItemId()){
        case R.id.Mapy:

            Intent intent = new Intent(this,Map.class);
            startActivity(intent);


            break;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
        return true;
    }

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="pl.pawelfrydrych.flyingball"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>

    <application

        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="pl.pawelfrydrych.flyingball.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
    </application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
</manifest>

public class Map extends MapActivity {

    private MapView mapView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.mapactivity);

        mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapview);

        mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        mapView.setTraffic(false);
        mapView.setSatellite(true);
        mapView.setStreetView(true);


    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

seems like you forgot to declare the Activity:

```
pl.pawelfrydrych.flyingball.Map
```

in your AndroidManifest.xml

---

Add something like that to Manifest.xml below the other `activity` tag:

```
    <activity
        android:name="pl.pawelfrydrych.flyingball.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <!-- add this here: -->
    <activity
        android:name="pl.pawelfrydrych.flyingball.Map"
        android:label="@string/map_title" >
    </activity>
```